# Custom Authorization class in Django Tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I used the following Custom Authorization class

```
class CustomDjangoAuthorization(DjangoAuthorization):
    def read_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        result = super(CustomDjangoAuthorization, self).read_detail(object_list, bundle)
        # now we check here for specific permission
        if bundle.request.user.profile.user_status:
            raise Unauthorized("You are not allowed to access that resource.")
        return result
```

It gives

> 401 Unauthorized

when the `user_status = 1`. But when I change the `user_status` to 0, it still shows

> 401 Unauthorized

error.

My unsends authorizationderstanding was that for each request, tastypie checks Authorization and gives a 200 response for Ok and 401 for Unauthorized. Am I missing something here?

Hey Sean, I tried moving custom code before super. I get a

> AttributeError: ‘AnonymousUser’ object has no attribute ‘profile’

Everything is working in localhost, production is giving a problem.
This happens in both cases, when `user_status = 1` & when `user_status = 0`

Using Django 1.8 and Tastypie 0.13.3.

Comment: It is quite possible that your call to super() returns 401 for some unconnected reason and you return it to the user. Might want to check what result is in the result :)

Comment: Ah, the DjangoAuthorization does require you to be logged in, hence the `‘AnonymousUser’ object has no attribute ‘profile’` error I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your custom code before the call to `super()`, and add a check to see if the user is anonymous:

```
class CustomDjangoAuthorization(DjangoAuthorization):
   def read_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
    # check here for specific permission
    if (not bundle.request.user.is_authenticated()) or bundle.request.user.profile.user_status:
        raise Unauthorized("You are not allowed to access that resource.")
    result = super(CustomDjangoAuthorization, self).read_detail(object_list, bundle)
    return result
```

You were getting `AttributeError: ‘AnonymousUser’ object has no attribute ‘profile’` because your user was logged out, so `request.user` was an `AnonymousUser`, therefore no `profile`.

Comment: My User was not logged out. He is authenticated as I can see the API Key and username in my request. It should not raise `Unauthorized` when user_status = 1. 

Its working fine in my localhost, not in production.

Comment: Your User *is* logged out, otherwise you wouldn't have an `AnonymousUser`. You may be sending auth data, but clearly your server isn't doing anything with it. If it's working in dev but not prod, that points to an issue with either your prod code being out of date or the server configs being wrong. Verify your auth headers are making it through to whatever process is running your Django project.

Comment: Yes you are right, have given an explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Sean Hayes is right, my user was logged out. I am using a custom url and didn't know that it didn't take my APIAuthentication by default.

I had to add `self.is_authenticated(request)` in my custom method for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Your code and symptoms I guess You have bad authorization details. Check Your `username` and `api_key`. Probably You have typo or You use a local authorization details on production.

Comment: Yes, my url was not getting authenticated. See my answer for details.